# Changing href attribute leveraging Javascript

Tags: javascript

Currently looking to dynamical change the `href` attribute on the `<a>` tag leveraging some Javascript. For context, I want to have a readily available snippet that can do this on a google search in order to highlight a faux user's journey (I work for a company that sells a chatbot tool and the goal is to show how we can make the experience specific to the user if they clicked on an ad). This is strictly for demonstration purposes and would not be code I execute outside of my local machine.

I found a code block on another post (cannot seem to locate it now) and have the following:

```
function changeHyperlink () {

for (var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
    anchors[i].href = "www.drift-demo.com"
}
}

changeHyperlink();
```

This works, however, all the links on the google page have a prepending `href` attribute of `https://www.google.com` so all the links now are `https://www.google.com/newurl.com`. My end goal is to have all the links be specific to `newurl.com`.

I don't know how this happening as all the `href` attributes (in the HTML code) are `newurl.com`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When setting the `href`, include the protocol, eg `http` or `https`:

```js
const anchors = document.querySelectorAll('a');
function changeHyperlink() {
  for (var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
    anchors[i].href = "https://www.drift-demo.com";
  }
}

changeHyperlink();
```

```html
<a>some anchor</a>
```

Comment: That worked! Appreciate the insight. Cannot believe I forgot to be explicit with the protocol!